# zabbix authentication with IBM Lotus Domino

Tags: active-directory, ldap, lotus-domino, zabbix

Do some of u guys have some experience with authentication in zabbix using lotus domino? Im not quite sure what to enter there. I know i made some authentication for IBM WebSphere but i cant get it working in zabbix. Can someone give me some tutorial? or explanations? :)

There is :

```
  LDAP HOST : mydomino.local.address
  Port : 389 
  Base DN : ???What is this???
  Search attribute : cn;
  Bind DN : ???my 'sudo'user / binduser???
  Bind password : binduser.password
```

Ok so I tried it. Also i can easily telnet "mydomino.local.address" on 389 port. So there is nothing bad with connection. Maybe Base DN. Is this something special - unique for each LDAP server like "mycompany DomainName?" or can it be something universal? Alsosearch attribute. I know cn; or uid; or mail; works in WAS.

I would be really glad if someone could just help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Domino there are different "Base DNs". For a user search the Base DN typically is `o=YourOrganizer`, so if your Notesnames look like `CN=MartinFric/OU1=IT/O=YourCompany`, then the base DN would be `o=YourCompany`.

Groups do NOT have a Base- DN. If you search for groups, then the Base DN has to be empty.

Bind- DN depends on the configuration of your Domino. Your mail- address will always work as well as your CN- name. So this might be "Martin Fric" or "martin.fric@yourcompany.com". Other variations might work as well. The bind password is the Internet- Password of the bind user (HTTP Password in person document in domino directory).

Usually one creates a specific LDAPBind user in the directory with an internet password to not expose user- passwords to any external program.

The search- attributes depend on what you want to achieve.

Open the Lotus- Notes- Program- Directory of any installed Lotus Notes client in a CMD and type the following:

```
ldapsearch.exe -h mydomino.local.address -p 389 -D "Martin Fric" 
  -w YourInternetPassword "(CN=Martin Fric)"
```

In this query the parameters are:

- -h = LDAP HOST
- -p = Port
- -D = Bind DN
- -w = Bind Password
- "(cn=Martin Fric)" = Query that sais: Search in (Search attribute) cn for an entry with value "Martin Fric"

If this query succeeeds and the query returns values, then the parameters for zabbix are correct. In that case someone knowing zabbix has to help you further in debugging that.

If this query does NOT succeed, then you need to fix your domino -> Come back with the error mmessage you get for help.

Comment: Ok i now have new information. But. What to do next. There is lot of information. Used Base-DN : 'O=mycompany'. Bind-DN : "CN=Martin Fric". But what next? :D still no help. Worst thing is i cant even see what is bad. There is no error message when i test connection and it just dont work.

Comment: please check out my edits. Try to trace down with this information, if Domino is your problem or zabbix

Comment: Thanks you for edit. It is nice to understand now. I know how to parse some things in 'domino queries' using commands. Biggest problem is that zabbix just cant continue without Base DN specified! And second question. Is it possible to process multiple search attributes??

Comment: To search for multiple attributes the query would be `"|((CN=Martin Fric)(sn=Fric))"`. This query would search for all people with CN=Martin Fric or all People with lastname (sn)=Fric. `| = OR`, `& = AND`